# df.plot gives only a single column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a code that goes as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('train.txt', delimiter=':', header=None, names=['0', '1', '2', 'loss', 'acc'])
# some modifications to df
df['iter'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df.head()

# method 1
df.plot(x='iter', y=['acc', 'loss'])
plt.show()
# method 2
df[['acc', 'loss']].plot()
plt.show()
```

Output of `df.head()`:

```
    loss    acc     iter
0   1.0894  0.1619  1
1   0.8992  0.1628  2
2   0.8305  0.1618  3
3   0.7961  0.1590  4
4   0.7755  0.1671  5
```

I thought it will give me both `loss` and `acc` in the same plot, but instead it (both of the methods written above) only gives me `acc` on the line graph.

I also tried `df.plot()`, and strangely it prints both `iter` and `acc`, but not `loss`. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks...

EDIT:

Output obtained
[image]

Comment: I ran your code and got both acc and loss in the same plot

Comment: For me it works fine. What do you get? Include a figure in your question

Comment: @JohanC 0.25.3 (latest is 1.4.0). I'll try latest, give me a moment

Comment: Method 1 works for me and show 2 plots. double check if both `loss` and `acc` are numerical type with `df.dtypes`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't know why, but `loss` was string type. I changed it to float, and it works like a charm. Thank you!!!